# how to show website links as html rather than querystring using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, querystringparameter

i have website links as given below.

justrite.pl/exam.php?code=/product1.htm

justrite.pl/exam.php?code=/product2.htm

justrite.pl/exam.php?code=/product3.htm

and many products like product4,product5......product100

If anyone will visit the site should see these links as given below

justrite.pl/product1.htm

justrite.pl/product2.htm

justrite.pl/product3.htm

please help in achieving it using htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.htaccess` rules as like that:

```
RewriteRule ^product1.htm$ exam.php?code=product1.htm [L]
RewriteRule ^product2.htm$ exam.php?code=product1.htm [L]
RewriteRule ^product3.htm$ exam.php?code=product1.htm [L]
```

Add more as you can.

Comment: i was hoping that rather than entering the rewriterule for 100 times, i can get a single rewrite rule.

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*).htm$ exam.php?code=$1.htm [L]  @SNazia

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME}   !-d
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME}   !-f
RewriteRule   (.*)                  /exam.php?code=$1   [L]
```

It's also checking if there's a directory or file with the originally requested name so it won't redirect them.